# Element not found error using python selenium driver

Tags: python, selenium

I am getting the element not found error to type input in the search element

[image]

Code used by me :

```
 browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id='pubicationQuery'][name='publicationQuery']").click()
```

browser is my webDriver selenium object. 
I have tried class name, also `X` path but unable to locate the element.

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: input[id='pubicationQuery'][name='publicationQuery']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) here. Also, please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. In future, please post the actual code in text and [not in a picture](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). It is more helpful if your code is given this way because if we need to run it we can copy and paste.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException" when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome)

Comment: Still same error selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: input[id='publicationQuery'][name='publicationQuery']

Answer (score 3):

From what I can understand from the error and the image you added, it just a typo

in the code below id should be publicationQuery and not pubicationQuery.

**EDIT** - forgot to fix the typo

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id='publicationQuery'][name='publicationQuery']").click()
```

Comment: I still don't see any code changes between you and OP. Perhaps you missed out to implement the change you spoke about in your solution.

Comment: Great catch (+1) This should nail the OP.

Comment: @DebanjanB op wrote 'pubicationQuery'